# Android Image Loading Memory Mangment

Tags: android, memory-management, android-glide, android-bitmap

I have an App where it gets data from Api which includes Images and i show them inside an RecyclerView and items number will increase as long as the user scroll... I have been trying different library's to display images and still can't reach a good result, I have tested Using Glide and Fresco and I reached the best result for now using glide but it's not good enough and pixelated

Glide Code:

```
Glide.with(holder.gameImage)
            .load(itemViewModel.thumb)
            .skipMemoryCache( true )
            .apply(RequestOptions().override(holder.gameImage.width, holder.gameImage.height))
            .centerInside()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)
            .error(R.drawable.no_image_found)
            .into(holder.gameImage)
```

RecyclerView onViewRecycled:

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)
    Glide.with(holder.gameImage).clear(holder.gameImage)
}
```

Glide Memory Usage after 150+ items:

[image: Glide Memory Usage]

Fresco Code:

```
val frescoRequest: ImageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder
            .newBuilderWithSource(itemViewModel.thumb.toUri())
            .setResizeOptions(ResizeOptions(holder.layout.width,holder.layout.height)).build()
        holder.gameImage.controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder().setOldController(holder.gameImage.controller).setImageRequest(frescoRequest).build()
```

Fresco Memory Usage after 150+ items:

[image: Fresco Memory Result]

-In fresco Test the format is ARGB_8888
-In Glide Test the format is RGB_565

Booth of tests I scaled the Image Size to be same size as the ImageView and still the fresco used much more memory but the images are more clear not like glide pixelated

-I have tried changing the image format for better and stable memory usage but the results are pixelated now and 250mb memory usage is too much
-And why there's almost 50mb 'Others' in my memory profiler ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this API offer you a thumbnail URL? If yes, use them instead, if the user clicks on any image then load the full resolution one, also have you tried `.override(size,size);` this method will resize your image to a specific size

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI yes I am resizing the image to fit the ImageViewsize so i don't load bigger image that will use more memory for no reason,I will try loading the thumbnail